# Programmatically Using Androids Loading Spinners

Tags: android

I'm currently wanting to use the Android's system Spinners, which is located at `..\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\`

I currently have the .png files example `spinner_white_48.png`

and animation xml `progress_medium_holo.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_outer_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The following does not work:

```
         // Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
         // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
         ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
         img.setBackgroundResource(my.package.R.drawable.progress_medium_holo);

         // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
         AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

         // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
         frameAnimation.start();
```

I am receving the error now:

```
12-05 23:31:15.731: E/AndroidRuntime(30685): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
```

I cannot find any info on how to programmatically implement these.

Comment: Did you try to rename the progress_medium_holo into something else, maybe `my_progress_medium_holo`? Also, rename the png files as well

Comment: Just tried, didn't work I'm afraid!

Comment: Who is `R` targetting? Is it `android.R` or `your_package_name.R` ?

Comment: I tried using my.package.R however I got this exception: 12-05 23:25:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(29191): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_medium_holo.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02001e

Comment: @KarlMorrison Are you sure there are no mispellings?

Comment: indeed I am, the progress_medium_halo in the my.package.R.drawable.progress_medium_halo is that italic/blue style so it's found it :/

Comment: However now I'm getting another error: 12-05 23:31:15.731: E/AndroidRuntime(30685): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable